# Fetching data into drop down from php through ajax

Tags: php, json, jquery

Okay i have to drop down boxes, now when the the selects an item in dropdown box A, it should use that selected value as a parameter within the php and use the result of the query to populate dropdown box B.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>    
</head>   
<body>
<select name="sel1" id="sel1">
    <option>Alphabets</option>
    <option>Numbers</option>
</select>

<select name="sel2" id="sel2">
    <option></option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

When i select 'Alphabets' in 'sel1' it should populate 'sel2' with alphabets, if i select 'Numbers' in sel1 it should populate sel2 with numbers. I hope that is clear enough, i'm new to PHP so i really need help with this ajax postback stuff.

Comment: Not that you want to go this route, but since you haven't really added any code on your own, maybe look at this class http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8041-PHP-Create-multiple-dropdown-selects-lists.html it does what you're trying to do and may be easier for you to get working.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) Please post the code that you have attempted. There are many examples here on stackoverflow, and no one wants to do the work for you. ie. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ajax+dropdown or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ajax+dynamic+dropdown

Comment: what you have tried yet ?

Comment: New to php, don't know how to go about it, i just found out how to get and post single values to and from the server but not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jvascript event on change to call a function inside which you can run a php query and populate results.

```
<select name="sel1" id="sel1" onchange='funct()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should add `onChange="selec()"`

```
    function selec(){
    var getdata = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    $.ajax({
url:your php,
dataType:"json",
contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
data:your parameter of json,
type:"GET",
success: function(jsondata){

}
});

    }
```